# Understanding CSS transform that does not trigger layout

Tags: css, css-transforms

I read that some CSS transform properties do not trigger layout:

scale, rotate, position, opacity

This might be an obvious question, but does that mean they will always be applied independently regardless of other contents on the page?

For example, when I change a position property with translate(x,y) to move down a box, will it not push the contents below? I made a [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/kta6nkh3/) myself, and it seems that changing position is completely out of the dom flow.

Comment: position and opacity are not transforms. And they *do* affect layout.

Comment: @BoltClock according to https://csstriggers.com/opacity, `opacity` doesn't trigger layout in Blink/Gecko, but does trigger it in Webkit/Edge. Is this incorrect?

Comment: @Ilya Streltsyn: That sounds like a different definition of "layout" to me. Based on the wording of the question it seems the asker is referring to that, rather than "layout" as defined by the spec (layout is not "triggered" in the way it's being described here and in that link).

Comment: I guess so, too, based on the word 'trigger'. AFAIK, in terms of browser rendering performance, 'layout' is the same thing as 'reflow' (http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/#Layout).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you're right, `transform` will not cause other elements to flow around it. This is why the `div` on top will not push the `div` on bottom down with it.

Check [this](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform/#article-header-id-3) link for more description.